# Proof that a slope coefficient can be given as the covariance of y and residuals divided by the variance of residuals

Tags: self-study, econometrics

I want to show that the slope coefficient for the *j*th regressor for $i = 1, \dots, 2$ and $j = 1, \dots, k$ is given as

$$ b_j = \frac{Cov(y_j, u{_{ji}})}{Var(u_{ji})}$$

where $u_{ji}$ is the residual from a regression of $x_{ji}$ on all other covariates.

Comment: If this is for self study, you should probably tag it as such ([tag:self-study]) in order to get better guidance here.

Comment: I think you shoul remove the j index on y. Also maybe bother to write up the model. I am assuming we are in the setting of linear regression.

Comment: This is a FAQ: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+slope+formula.